# VimにVundleVimとその他のプラグインを.vimrcに記述したのですが、Vimを起動するたびにエラーが出ます。

Tags: vim

**現象**
Vimを起動するたびに、下記のエラーが出る。

```
/home/hogehoge/.vimrc の処理中にエラーが検出されました:
行   10:
E492: エディタのコマンドではありません: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
行   13:
E492: エディタのコマンドではありません: Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim' 
行   14:
E492: エディタのコマンドではありません: Plugin 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
行   15:
E492: エディタのコマンドではありません: Plugin 'vim-javascript'
行   16:
E492: エディタのコマンドではありません: Plugin 'turbio/bracey.vim' {'do': 'npm install --prefix server'}
行   18:
E117: 未知の関数です: vundle#end
```

**期待値**
上記のエラーを解消したい。

**再現手順**
`.vimrc`を下記のように記述してVimを起動する。

```
"設定
set number "行番号を表示する
set title "編集中のファイル名を表示
set showmatch "括弧入力時の対応する括弧を表示
syntax on "コードの色分け
set tabstop=4 "インデントをスペース4つ分に設定
set smartindent "自動でインデントを挿れる
set fenc=utf-8 "文字コードをUTF-8に設定

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
"導入したいプラグインを以下に列挙する
"Plugin '[Github Author]/[Github repo]'の形式で記入
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim' 
Plugin 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
Plugin 'vim-javascript'
Plugin 'turbio/bracey.vim' {'do': 'npm install --prefix server'}

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start に記載されている手順より

```
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
```

が抜けているので記載した上でリンク先の手順に従えば動くと思います。